# What is MakeFile in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

What is MakeFile in Eclipse? From the documentation:

> A makefile is a text file that is referenced by the make command that
>   describes the building of targets, and contains information such as
>   source-level dependencies and build-order dependencies.  The CDT can
>   generate a makefile for you, such projects are called Managed Make
>   projects. Some projects, known as Standard Make projects, allow you to
>   define your own makefile.

But the explanation does not help me understand what a MakeFile is. I am moving from VisualStudio/C# to Eclipse/C++. Is MakeFile analogous to Visual Studio's Metadata? When do I need to write a MakeFile, and why do I need it besides the C++ code?

[EDIT]
I used to develop on Windows with VS and C#. And now trying Eclipse/C++ on a Mac. I have never build anyone on Linux. So the answer I have read so far does not help explain anything at all.

Comment: Wikipedia has a surprisingly extensive introduction: [Make (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))

Comment: Any reason why you are not using visual studio/c++?

Comment: @JesseGood you can guess a number of reasons already without asking: cross-platform, open-source, standardized (Visual C++ has many non-standard features that aren't easy to avoid), learning Eclipse will help use it for a number of languages not available for Visual Studio, etc. These are the reasons you cannot argue with, but there are also personal preferences which I leave to the OP.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili: If the OP has used VisualStudio/C# up until now, I see very little merit in changing IDEs.

Comment: @JesseGood I don't understand you. If the OP has any of the reasons above, then he would need to leave Visual Studio to achieve his goals.

Comment: @JesseGood And besides production reasons, there is one great reason - learning. I've learned vi though I knew I was never gonna use it. Curiosity drives humanity. You seem to be the kind of person who learns only one thing and doesn't want to hear about other things anymore. Not everyone is like that.

Comment: @JesseGood I am not using VS/C++ because I am now using a Mac.

Comment: @KMC: In that case, you might want to look into [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: @GregHewgill "extensive" does not mean it actually explains things. I have read the wiki and does not find it to answer anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A makefile in the simplest terms is a file that builds a program. These are normally used from the command line. If you have ever built something on linux you may have run ./configure ; make ; make install. You are using a makefile there.

More info...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)

Comment: Why do I need a makefile since I already have a compiler that compile my C++ code. I have never used Linux. How can a file build a program? Do I have to write a file to compile my C++ code besides my code? The wiki is utterly confusing.

Comment: A compiler just takes code and converts it into a program. A makefile does a lot around that compiler. For instance with a make file you can say only rebuild files that I have edited since the last time I built this project. This means you save a lot of compile time. It might be helpful to google makefile tutorial as well.

Comment: Technically you don't need a makefile because you could type everything by hand yourself at the command prompt. However, imagine a project with 50 files, that would mean you have to type in every file name yourself every time you want to compile your project. With a makefile it saves you all that hand typing (there is a lot more to it than that though, but to keep the example simple).

Comment: @JesseGood I tried that on xCode, but MakeFile does not exist in xCode (or cannot find it). Is MakeFile only for Eclipse? Does absence of MakeFile on XCode restrict me to write cross-Platform C++ application on xCode?

Comment: @KMC: No, makefiles are a general tool used on many platforms. The reason Xcode does not have makefiles is because it uses its own internal projects files (.xcodeproj) to manage build processes. The absence of makefiles does not restrict code portability in any way. All they are is a piece of software to make managing and building programs easier. It seems that there are a lot of fundamental things you are missing, I would suggest reading some beginner C++ books which explain more about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms: Make helps you create cross-platform configuration settings in one file, and it will work on surprisingly many platforms, including Windows or Mac OS-es.

Mentioning Windows, you should have Make installed on the computer you're installing on (on Windows, Cygwin and MinGW include Make). It's required only if the user will actually *build the code from the source*.

But of course, you should include Make code for each different platform (e.g. one for Unix-like, one for Windows, etc.)